# Formtastic with multiple ajax calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, formtastic

I'm trying to figure out the rails way to use formtastic to build out a couple of dropdown boxes and then based on those values make some ajax calls.  For example:

1. At the top level my model is a PostOffice with a location_id
2. User selects dropdown #1 which is a list of states.
3. When dropdown #1 is changed dropdown #2 is populated with cities via an ajax call
4. When dropdown #2 is changed dropdown #3 is populated with addresses via an ajax call
5. User clicks 'get info' and the form submit happens.

Do I need to build out multiple semantic_form_for calls in my view to populate subsequent dropdown boxes?  I can get this to work using a bunch of jquery but it's resulting in some unmaintainable code.  Seems like I need to have it setup so that when I change dropdown #1 I need to make a request that generates a partial for dropdown #2.